# Как проверить какое именно событие срабатывает при .mousewheel

Tags: javascript, jquery

Как проверить какое именно событие срабатывает при `.mousewheel`

скрол мыши на вверх или скрол мыши вниз. При скроле вывод alertom

```
$('#bloc')
   .mousewheel(function (event, delta) {
    alert ();  //если вверх то показать 5 если вниз 3
   })
;
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34147719/3129992

Comment: Это не помогло.

Comment: Приведите полный пример неработающего кода, т.к. код по ссылке рабочий.

Comment: У меня в поле только когда я доходил до конца срабатывало, а мне нужно после каждой прокрутке.

Answer (score 0):

сделал так и работает:

```
 var elem = document.getElementById('bloc');

    if (elem.addEventListener) {
      if ('onwheel' in document) {
        // IE9+, FF17+
        elem.addEventListener("wheel", onWheel);
      } else if ('onmousewheel' in document) {
        // устаревший вариант события
        elem.addEventListener("mousewheel", onWheel);
      } else {
        // Firefox < 17
        elem.addEventListener("MozMousePixelScroll", onWheel);
      }
    } else { // IE8-
      elem.attachEvent("onmousewheel", onWheel);
    }


    // Это решение предусматривает поддержку IE8-
    function onWheel(e) {
      e = e || window.event;

      // deltaY, detail содержат пиксели
      // wheelDelta не дает возможность узнать количество пикселей
      // onwheel || MozMousePixelScroll || onmousewheel
      var delta = e.deltaY || e.detail || e.wheelDelta;

      if(delta > 0){

          alert ("555");
      }else{
         alert ("333"); 

      }


    }
```

Comment: весь твой ответ сводится к условию: `if(delta > 0){

          alert ("555");
      }else{
         alert ("333"); 

      }` его и вставь в свой обработчик